# Git: last merge commit ignored

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

These are my steps.

Step 1: Merge `develop` into `feature`

Step 2: Check if everything is OK and immediately afterwards merge `feature` into `develop`

When I did that I got the following situation:

[image: CURRENT]

Only "merge `develop` into `feature`" is shown and "merge `feature` into `develop`" is not shown.

I would like that both merge commits are shown, like in the following picture.

[image: WANTED]

Can someone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this fast enough, before anyone adds new commits to `develop`, then by default Git will do a fast-forward merge. To prevent it, just add `--no-ff` to your merge command back into `develop`:

```
git fetch
git branch -d develop # to make sure you aren't using an out of date copy
git checkout develop
git merge feature --no-ff
```

Side note: many workflows recommend rebasing `feature` onto `develop` before the merge back into `develop`, instead of merging `develop` into `feature` first.